# How to match "Client Hello ServerName" exactly using Tcl regexp?

Tags: regex, tcl, expect

My TCL script :

```
set line { 
Jul 24 21:06:40 2014: %AUTH-6-INFO: login[1765]: user 'admin' on 'pts/1' logged
Jul 24 21:05:15 2014: %DATAPLANE-5-: Unrecognized HTTP URL www.58.net. Flow: 0x2
Jul 24 21:04:39 2014: %DATAPLANE-5-: Unrecognized HTTP URL static.58.com. Flow:
Jul 24 21:04:38 2014: %DATAPLANE-5-: Unrecognized HTTP URL www.google-analytics.com. Flow: 0x2265394048.
Jul 24 21:04:36 2014: %DATAPLANE-5-: Unrecognized HTTP URL track.58.co.in. Flow: 0
Jul 24 21:04:38 2014: %DATAPLANE-5-:Unrecognized HTTP URL www.google.co.in. Flow: 0x87078800
Jul 24 21:04:38 2014: %DATAPLANE-5-:CCB:44:Unrecognized Client Hello ServerName www.google.co.in. Flow: 0x87073880. len_analyzed: 183
Jul 24 21:04:38 2014: %DATAPLANE-5-:CCB:44:Unrecognized Server Hello ServerName test1. Flow: 0x87073880, len_analyzed 99
Jul 24 21:04:38 2014: %DATAPLANE-5-:CCB:44:Unrecognized Server Cert CommonName *.google.com. Flow: 0x87073880
Jul 24 21:04:38 2014: %DATAPLANE-5-:CCB:44:Searching rname(TYPE_A) cs50.wac.edgecastcdn.net in dns_hash_table
Jul 24 21:04:38 2014: %DATAPLANE-5-:Unrecognized HTTP URL www.facebook.com. Flow: 0x87078800
Jul 24 21:04:38 2014: %DATAPLANE-5-:CCB:44:Unrecognized Client Hello ServerName www.fb.com. Flow: 0x87073880. len_analyzed: 183
Jul 24 21:05:38 2014: %DATAPLANE-5-:CCB:44:Unrecognized Server Hello ServerName test. Flow: 0x87073880, len_analyzed 99
Jul 24 21:04:38 2014: %DATAPLANE-5-:CCB:44:Unrecognized Server Cert CommonName *.facebook.com. Flow: 0x87073880
Jul 24 21:05:39 2014: %DATAPLANE-5-:CCB:44:Searching rname(TYPE_A) cs50.wac.facebook.net in dns_hash_table
}


set urls [list]
        foreach item [regexp -all -inline {Client[ ]Hello[ ]ServerName\s+\S+} $line] {
        lappend urls [lindex $item 1]
        }
        #puts $res
            set s "*****************************************************"
            set f {}
            set f [open output.txt a]
            if {$f ne {}} {

            foreach url $urls {
            chan puts $f $url

            }
            chan puts $f $s
            chan close $f
            }
```

I am trying to print the characters appearing after "Client Hello ServerName" in `$line`. I need to match exact "Client Hello ServerName" and use it in regexp to get the output. I tried `Client[ ]Hello[ ]ServerName`. But its not working.

output should be "www.google.co.in. www.fb.com." in output.txt file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could catch the string after *Client Hello ServerName* using braces `()`, e.g.:

```
foreach {dummy item} [regexp -all -inline {Client Hello ServerName\s+(\S+)} $line] {
  lappend urls $item
}
```

Answer (score 1):

trying testing your knowledge and patterns here: https://www.debuggex.com/
It's great for learning and checking if your getting exactly what you want.

Nevertheless:

```
set pattern {^.*Client Hello ServerName\s+(.*)\s+Flow.*$}
foreach element $line {
  set result [regexp $pattern $element match url]
  if {$url} {
    lappend urls $url
  }
}
```

**()** will match the pattern you desire. Using ' **.*** ' its an easy way to see whats being matches, adding a pattern to it may make it easier to think upon it.

If regexp matches then $result = 1, else $return = 0; If match happened append url matches to urls.

You can find more info upon tcl regexp at http://wiki.tcl.tk/986